# `style` property is `null` on element

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function displayMenu (newGal, newSub) {
    curGal = newGal;
    curSub = newSub;
    if (curGal == null) {
        curGal = "main";
    };
    arrayL = curGal.length;
    if (curImg == null) {
        curImg = 0;
    };
    if (curSub == null) {
        curSub = 0;
    };
    prevImg = curImg - 1;
    if (prevImg == null || prevImg < 0) {
        prevImg = arrayL;
    };
    nextImg = curImg + 1;
    document.getElementById('img1').style.display = "none";
};
```

And no matter what it's giving me that the `style` property is `null`. This code is massively torn down from what it used to be; this was part of a `for` loop that was supposed to use `i` to target `"img" + i` to select the `div`s with the `id` of `img0`-`9`, then I broke it down and tried manually targeting every single `img0`-`9` with a separate line and it just keeps breaking. Yes, the `img0`-`9` divs are in the HTML. The original `for` loop looked like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.L; i++) {
    var tempButton = "img" + i;
    document.getElementById(tempButton).style.display = "none";
};
```

**Why is the `style` property `null`, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Can you post your HTML and javascript together in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It seems most likely to me that you are calling `displayMenu()` before the elements have been loaded on the page. Is this the case?

Comment: Do you need that first two assignments? It seems unnecessary and also it seems that you're declaring those variables in the global scope. Also, comparing to `null` like that is unsafe, use the `||` assignment operator, you can GREATLY reduce your code.

Comment: You're only getting `#img1` in the loop? Element IDs should be unique.  Are you adding these elements dynamically? If so, you should also be creating a unique ID.

Comment: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EptYS/

Comment: Notice also that function declarations, as opposed to function assignments, don't have a semicolon after the closing bracket.

Comment: [Here's a cleaned-up JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XLkWM/)

Comment: displayMenu() is being called as window.onload, the elements are already going to be in the page, and the idea was that I would, on page load, hide all the ones I didn't need based on the quantity of images listed in the gallery arrays.  But I haven't even gotten that far because this just...meh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
window.onload = displayMenu('main', 0);
```

This is your problem. Use this instead:

```
window.onload = function() {displayMenu('main', 0);}
```

---

In your code, `displayMenu` is called and then the *return value* of that call is assigned to `window.onload`. This fails, because you are assigning `window.onload` before the `imgX` elements have been added.

In the solution, you are instead assigning a function literal to `window.onload` which, when called, runs `displayMenu`. It now works because the elements have been placed on the page.

Comment: In addition, displayMenu() is defined twice, which was actually part 2 of his issue.

Comment: Actually that's a non-issue, @David. Sure, it's not the best idea, but it doesn't cause any problems because the "actual" function is defined after the "bogus" one.

Comment: Gah, awesome.  Okay, so when I declare a window.onload, I should use:  "window.onload = function() {myfunctionhere(stuff)};" always?  I thought the purpose of saying window.onload was that it would wait until the entire window loaded before running the code.  And yeah, sorry, this code is nowhere near complete and I keep getting interrupted while doing it, thus the double declaration of the same function.

Comment: `window.onload` does indeed wait until the page has fully loaded, but the code that creates the `window.onload` runs immediately. Since you were telling it to run something immediately, it happily did so, then happily crashed.

Answer (score 1):

In your jsFiddle, you the function `displayMenu()` defined twice, which would break it.